# how to support our own data formate in rest jaxrs to excahnge between client and server

Tags: java, jax-rs

i want to support our own data formate like cvv in restful service jaxrs

```
example 
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.OurType)
public Response get(query() int awbn) {
    Response response = null;
       smaple sa=new sample();
        response = Response.ok().entity(sa).build();
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `JAX-RS` to implement the web service, you can specify a custom Media Type and it should work out of the box.

Try:`@Produces("application/YourCustomMediaType")`.